# EFCore - POST-Request returns "The X field is required"

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, odata

I am trying to create a POST-Method for mailing using EFCore and OData in ASP .NET. When sending the request via Postman it returns a 400 - "The request field is required". I have no idea what the problem could be. The request contains form-data with all specified fields, any ideas what the problem is?

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("mail")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Mail([FromBody] SupplierMailDto request) =>
        await Handle(Service.WriteMail(request));
```

[image: Screenshot of the request and answer]

SupplierMailDto contains all the fields specified above.

```
public record SupplierMailDto : ISupplierMailDto 
{
    public String? Subject  {get; set;}

    public String? Message  {get; set;}

    public UInt64? UserId   {get; set;}

    public String? UserName {get; set;}

    public String? Receiver {get; set;}
}
```

However, the program doesnt actually enter the method. Any ideas?

Before using the SupplierMailDto I tried using the actual entity, but this also didnt work. I tried changing the form of the request, with no success.

Comment: Please add your definition for `SupplierMailDto`.

Comment: This error is returned by the ModelState of your model

Comment: @burnsi Added the definition

Answer (score 1):

You specify `[FromBody]` attribute for a data source, but you send your data as a form, so there is a mismatch. You should either change the attribute to `[FromForm]` or change the request format (for example, make it a raw body with JSON content and change `Content-Type` header to `application/json`).

Comment: Tried that already, sending it as raw json has the same result

Comment: @TaCqz But did you set the header as well?

Comment: Postman automatically changes the headers, but yes, I also tried setting them manually. Sending it as form data with the application/json header works well for all other entities

Comment: @TaCqz any solution to this? I am running into a similar issue...

Comment: @user2253546 Solution for me was to change it to [FromForm], since the Frontend was sending requests as multipart/form-data. It didnt recognize the Dto any other way, so I head to switch it to use form-data as well